# How to get a link with a clipped path and beveled edges?

Tags: css

I'm still a bit new to CSS, and I've been trying to get a button/link to look like this:

[image: Clipped path with beveled edges link/button]

I was able to cut the corners using polygon and clip path, but when I try to add beveled edges using an inner border radius, it gets clipped.

This is what I've got at the moment:

CSS

```
  .hero-introduction a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
  box-shadow:
        inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4),
        inset 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4),
        inset 0 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.05),
        2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        border-radius: 4px;
  background: #3b9921;
  color: #fff;
  clip-path: polygon(
    10% 0,
    90% 0,
    100% 20%,
    100% 80%,
    90% 100%,
    0 100%,
    0% 20%
  );
}

.hero-introduction a:before, .hero-introduction a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    height: 3px;
    
}
.hero-introduction a:before {
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    
}
.hero-introduction a:after {
    bottom: 0;  
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="hero-introduction flex">
          <h2>Hero Text Big</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <a href="#learnmore">Learn More</a>
        </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you also provide your html code?

Comment: @miftahulrespati just included the HTML now, nothing too intense.